# how to add elements within a list together in clojure?

Tags: list, clojure

I am trying to make a function that add elements within a list like below

editted to "Nathan Davis" correction without nil:

```
   (defn sumv [s1]
    (for [x1 s1 x2 s1
    :when (< x1 x2)]
     (+ x1 x2)))
```

Comment: I'm not following how your example result is derived from your sample data.  And your code doesn't help clarify things either.  Where's the `<` check coming from?  Please give us a formula or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explicitly use recursion, consider also using `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn add-pairs [[x & [y :as r]]]             
 (lazy-seq                                   
   (if y                                     
     (cons (+ x y) (add-pairs r)))))
```

Comment: The question has been revised to no longer require a recursive solution. In that case, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496412/clojure-how-to-add-successive-pairs-in-vector) covers it.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear enough, so I'll guess what you want.

If you want to add every two element then you should do:

```
(map #(apply + %) (partition 2 1 s1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the question exactly what you are trying to compute, so I can't give you a complete answer without further details.

However, I can tell you that the reason you are getting `nil`s in your result is because the body of your `for` returns the value of a one-armed `if`.  `(if a x)` is the same as `(if a x nil)`.  In other words, both expressions will evaluate to `nil` if `a` is falsey.

If your intention was to use the `if` statement to filter out cases where `x2 >= x1` (i.e., include only cases where `x1 < x2`), then you can accomplish this by including a `:when` clause with your `for` bindings:

```
 (defn sumv [s1]
  (for [x1 s1 x2 s1
        :when (< x1 x2)]
    (+ x1 x2)))
```

**Update for edited code**

```
(for [x s1
      y s2]
  <some-expression>)
```

is essentially the same as

```
(for [x s1]
  (for [y s2]
    <some-expression>))
```

That is, it's like using nested loops — it operates over the cartesian product of the sequences.

There are several ways to get what you want, but a simple `map` is probably the best:

```
(map + s1 (rest s1))
```

You can use `partition` if you want (a la @manzur's answer), although then you have to use `apply`.